# Sinatra-activerecord Table Not Found Error

Tags: sqlite, activerecord, sinatra

I have a simple sinatra-activerecord app. Inside the file ./config/environments.rb I have the following configurations:

```
configure :development, :test do
  set :database, 'sqlite://database.db'
end

# These Heroku setup instructions can be at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack
configure :production do
  # Database connection
  db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/mydb')

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter  => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
    :host     => db.host,
    :username => db.user,
    :password => db.password,
    :database => db.path[1..-1],
    :encoding => 'utf8'
  )
end
```

When I push to Heroku, the DB setup works just fine. However, locally, it doesn't. For example, if I do

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

I get the following fine output:

```
==  CreateHotels: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:hotels)
   -> 0.0015s
-- add_index(:hotels, :hotel_name)
   -> 0.0004s
==  CreateHotels: migrated (0.0021s) ==========================================
```

Now, if I start the server and use curl to make a call:

```
$ shotgun app.rb
$ curl -d "hotel_name=Sheraton" http://127.0.0.1:9393/hotels/
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - Could not find table 'hotels':
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:472:in `table_structure'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:346:in `columns'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `yield'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:243:in `column_defaults'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:482:in `initialize'
    /Users/Sy/Developer/Sinatra/stay-checkin-api/routes/hotels_routes.rb:8:in `new'
    /Users/Sy/Developer/Sinatra/stay-checkin-api/routes/hotels_routes.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1265:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1265:in `block in compile!'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:835:in `[]'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:835:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:851:in `route_eval'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:835:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:872:in `block in process_route'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:870:in `catch'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:870:in `process_route'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:834:in `block in route!'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:833:in `each'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:833:in `route!'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:936:in `dispatch!'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:769:in `block in call!'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:921:in `block in invoke'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:921:in `catch'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:921:in `invoke'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:769:in `call!'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:755:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:47:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/nulllogger.rb:9:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:99:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1389:in `block in call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1471:in `synchronize'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1389:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lint.rb:48:in `_call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lint.rb:36:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:20:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:136:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:86:in `proceed_as_child'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:31:in `call!'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:18:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/favicon.rb:12:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/shotgun-0.9/bin/shotgun:156:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/shotgun:19:in `load'
    /Users/Sy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/shotgun:19:in `<main>'
```

Any idea?

ps: here are my app.rb, config.rb, routes, and model file.

**app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'uri'
require './config/environments'


require_relative 'models/init'
require_relative 'routes/init'
```

**config.rb**

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

**model: hotel.rb**

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :hotel_name, :presence => true    
end
```

**routes: hotels_routes.rb**

```
get '/hotels' do
  @hotels = Hotel.all
  if @hotels
      content_type :json
      @hotels.to_json
  end
end


post '/hotels/' do
  @hotel = Hotel.new
  @hotel.hotel_name = params[:hotel_name]
  if @hotel.save 
    content_type :json
    @hotel.to_json
  else
    content_type :json
    "Failed to create new hotel with name #{params[:hotel_name]}".to_json
  end
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source :rubygems

gem 'heroku'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'activerecord'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord'
gem 'json'

# Define which database gem to use depending on whether you are in local or production environment

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg' # this gem is required to use postgres on Heroku
end
```

**Rakefile**

```
require './app'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
```

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) Have you confirmed the DB set up works fine on Heroku, or are you assuming that because it gave you no errors? 2) Have you checked the sqlite database via the command line client? I'll also suggest right now that you install postgres and develop against it, it's not hard and will save you bother in the long run, if not the short. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-postgresql

Comment: yep, i made a few api calls to the heroku and got valid json response. Not too trusting, i did check the logs and it was fine. I think i will follow your advice and develop against postgres locally. I did a bunch of research before asking this question and did see some people back a few months saying that sinatra+sqlite locally wasn't worth the trouble. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database set is wrong, try:

```
set :database, 'sqlite:///database.db'
```